# Protect ranges based on a specific values

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I have created spreadsheet to prepare month tasks for several people.
Now i would like to write script to automatically update protection settings.
How it looks?

I have list of people in column A and their emails in column E. I would like to create script to automatically update protections that allows edit only row where specific person is.

For example - User1 with email: email1@google.com can edit only row 8:8 and only him and me and nobody else.

[image: spreadsheet]

I got error.

```js
function zakresychronione() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var ochronadanych = ss.getSheetByName('Dyspozycje')
  var p1 = ochronadanych.getRange('8:8').protect();
  var p1val = ochronadanych.getRange('E8').getValue()
      p1.remove()
      p1.addEditor(p1val)}
```

I tried to do it step by step but it takes long time, i think loop would be better, but i don't know how to use them.

Comment: If you can provide the error, it's easier for us to help you out.

Comment: @sebook, was your issue solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for the script to loop through all the rows every time the protections need to be updated. You can create an onEdit trigger that checks which row was edited and only updates that specific protection.

Taking this into account, I wrote some code that does the following:

Everytime an email is edited (column 5, row index bigger than 7) the protections for that specific row should get updated. The only editors for that row would be you (change your email accordingly in the code) and the person whose email matches the one written in the cell:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var editedRange = e.range; // Range that was edited (info coming from event object)
  var sheetName = 'Dyspozycje';
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var column = 5;
  // Getting edited cell column and row index
  var editedCol = editedRange.getColumn();
  var editedRow = editedRange.getRow();
  // Checking the edited cell corresponds to an email
  if(editedRow > 7 && editedCol == column) { 
    var numCols = sheet.getMaxColumns();
    // Row that needs protection update
    var range = sheet.getRange(editedRow, 1, 1, numCols);
    // Creating protection
    var protection = range.protect().setDescription(editedRow);
    // Getting emails from desired editors
    var me = 'your_email@domain.com'; // Change accordingly
    var email = sheet.getRange(editedRow, editedCol).getValue();
    // Remove previous editors
    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
    // Add desired editors
    protection.addEditors([me, email]);
    if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
      protection.setDomainEdit(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Also, because at first no protection will be set, run this once to set them for each row (after this first time, there will be no need to run this; protections will update automatically thanks to the onEdit trigger):

```
function createProtections() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var emailColumn = 5;
  for(var i = 8; i < values.length; i++) {
    var numCols = sheet.getMaxColumns();
    var range = sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, numCols);
    var protection = range.protect().setDescription(i);
    var me = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
    var email = sheet.getRange(i, emailColumn).getValue();
    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
    protection.addEditors([me, email]);
    if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
      protection.setDomainEdit(false);
    }   
  }
}
```

I hope this is of any help.

Answer (score 0):

More info about problem:

```js
[19-11-02 02:06:23:553 PDT] Starting execution
[19-11-02 02:06:23:576 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0.016 seconds]
[19-11-02 02:06:23:638 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Dyspozycje]) [0.062 seconds]
[19-11-02 02:06:23:639 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([8:8]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-02 02:06:24:306 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.protect() [0.666 seconds]
[19-11-02 02:06:24:307 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([E8]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-02 02:06:24:512 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0.205 seconds]
[19-11-02 02:06:24:513 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.Protection.remove() [0 seconds]
[19-11-02 02:06:24:873 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.Protection.addEditor([tychy.polnoc@gmail.com]) [0.359 seconds]
[19-11-02 02:06:25:304 PDT] Execution failed: Błąd usługi: Arkusze kalkulacyjne (line 7, file "makra") [1.393 seconds total runtime]
```

Strange thing is that when I write that email in script manually all works.

Comment: You remove the protection, and then you want to add editor, I think this is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Here an example to loop, and I remove p1.remove():

```
function zakresychronione() {
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ochronadanych = ss.getSheetByName('Dyspozycje')

  var lstRow=ochronadanych.getLastRow();
  for (i=8;i<lstRow+1;i++)
  {
    var p1 = ochronadanych.getRange(i + ':' + i).protect();
    var p1val = ochronadanych.getRange('E' + i).getValue()
    p1.addEditor(p1val);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, thank you very much. Because of you I've understood loops. Iamblichus I've used your scripts and they are amazing and helped me to create what I want. . But there was only one problem, every time i edited email the script created next one protected range with actual user. When I added new email in blank cell it created two protected ranges - one which allowed only me to edit range and another one which allowed to edit range for me and that email. I tried to understand why, but I don't know. I decided to modify all your scripts and now is great 
I used it to remove protections and create new and I created status bar which shows how many protections range need to be created for example 4/35, 5/35 ect.
I will not update protections often so it's OK. 
Thank you all and especially Iamblichus.

Best regards
Sebastian